# Haskell Garbage collection fails to reclaim sufficient space

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and i am doing a higher order function homework while using Hugs.Wanted to know if there is a fix to it. Is it the itsHug's problem or my code's?

```
proj :: [u] -> (u -> Int -> v) -> [v]
proj [] f = []
proj s f = proj [ x | x <- s] f
```

error

```
Garbage collection fails to reclaim sufficient space
```

Comment: Hugs is not maintained for more than fourteen years. Normally one uses `ghc` nowadays.

Comment: Note that  `[ x | x <- s ]`, is just `s`, so it makes not much sense to do that. That means that you defined `proj s f = proj s f`, which is basically infinite recursion.

Comment: Haha indeed i noticed while searching for an answer but I'm afraid i cannot use it for my assignment.

Comment: well the two are in essence just Haskell compilers, but the difference is the GHC project is *active*, and thus bugs in the compiler get fixed, optimizations are implemented, new extensions are made, but the start from more or less the same core language, although GHC supports Haskell 2010, whereas Hugs probably (given the date of the last release) implements Haskell 1998.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*Hugs* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugs) is not maintained for over thirteen years now. The latest release was in september 2006. The [*Glasgow Haskell compiler* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasgow_Haskell_Compiler) is now the de-facto standard.

Your program however will normally get stuck in infinite recursion, unless the list is empty. Indeed `[ x | x <- s]` is just equivalent to `s`, so you basically wrote:

```
proj :: [u] -> (u -> Int -> v) -> [v]
proj [] f = []
proj s f = proj s f  -- call with the same parameters.
```

This thus means that in case the first parameter is not an empty list, you will keep calling the same function with the same parameters, and thus get stuck in an infinite loop, or until memory is exhausted in some way. Your program thus will often not stop, which is probably something you should fix.

Comment: Did you mean to say that GHC is *now* the de-facto standard?

Comment: @MarceloZabani: thanks, I should have been "Is *now* the de-facto standard" :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem did you mean to say *it* should have been? 